# Correct alignment and size of tables

Tags: html, asp.net, html-table

[image]

As you can see from my two tables, one is a different size to the other. 
My first question being, why is this? when I have set the width of the `<th>` in the top table to 100/300/100/100/100 (=700), and in the bottom table 500/100/100 (=700)

2. I would like to set the first column in the lower table to invisible, as I only want to see the summary and totals of the bottom table. Also I would like the aligned with the right hand side of the upper table. Any ideas or advice would be appreciated.  Is it something to do with setting the border in the style?

If I try border-left for example I am allowed to add border-width, border-style, border-colour, inherit?

(Table 2)

```
 <table class="detailstable StartOnNewPage" align="center">
        <tr>          

                <th style="width:500px;"></th>  
                <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Summary</th>   
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"></th>        
        </tr>
        <tr>                  
                <td style="width:500px;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Labour</td>
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(LabourTotal)%></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>              
                <td style="width:500px;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:left; width:100px; border-top:yes;">Plant</td>
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(PlantTotal)%></th>                   
        </tr>
        <tr>
                <td style="width:500px;"></td>                     
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.DisplayPlantPercentage%></th>    
                <td style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.PlantToDisplayWithTwoDecimalPlaces%></td> 
        </tr>
         <tr>                 
                <td style="width:500px;"></td>
                <td style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Miscellaneous</td> 
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px" class="FadeOutOnEdit"><%: this.FormatMoney(MiscellaneousItemsTotal) %></th>                 
         </tr>
         <tr>
                <td style="width:500px;"></td>                     
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.DisplayMiscellaneousPercentage%></th>    
                <td style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.MiscellaneousToDisplayWithTwoDecimalPlaces%></td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>   
                <td style="width:500px;"></td>
                <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">TOTAL</th> 
                <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(TotalOfAll)%></th>                 
        </tr>
        </table>
```

**Now Looks like:**
[image]

Comment: Did you paste in the correct table here?

Comment: yeah thats my code for the bottom table

Comment: try the table width attribute = 700px of both tables.

Comment: You mean remove the width of each one and set the overall to 700px? please see my edit for the new image, the table is slightly to the right, I would like to align vertially straight to the first table

Comment: No need to set width to 700 px, table will get aligned to right and would show properly. Check the answer below

Comment: yeah thanks for that, I have the first table set to align="center", and the bottom is "right", how can i move the bottom table slightly to the left, to line up vertically?

Comment: After implimenting Ravia's Answer. Try setting the outer div's width= 700 or something so that it will not move to the right.

Answer (score 0):

For lower table remove the first column and use table attribute align as shown below

```
<table class="detailstable StartOnNewPage" align="right">
    <tr>          
    <th style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Summary</th>   
            <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"></th>        
    </tr>
    <tr>                  
            <td style="text-align:left; width:100px;">Labour</td>
            <th style="text-align:right; width:100px;"><%: this.FormatMoney(LabourTotal)%></th>
    </tr>
```

....

Comment: thanks man that resolved it, please see my edit an an additional prob

Comment: Yeah the first column is now invisible but I still hve a problem with vertically alignement, please see new pic in my 'edit' of original post